# Wireshark capture packet in host-only VM

Tags: vmware, wireshark, host-only

I have 3 VMs: Pfsense, Kali and Windows XP (kali and window use host-only VMnet1, Pfsense 1 interface uses VMnet1 and one uses NAT). I open Wireshark on Kali machine, then I make a DNS request on Window XP and Wireshark on Kali can capture all traffics from WinXP. I don't understand why it can do that. Please help me know! Thank you!